# Change the size of a fill sample in Matlab legend

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm creating a plot in matlab that includes some lines, as well as a fill.  For example,

```
fill([0 1 1], [0 1 0], [.9 .9 .9]);
plot(rand(5, 1), 'b');
plot(rand(5, 1), 'r');
plot(rand(5, 1), 'g');
legend('fill', 'line one', 'line two', 'line three');
```

I can change the length of the sample lines in the legend with:

```
f = findobj('type', 'line');
set(f(2), 'XData', [.2, .3]); % Changes line three
set(f(4), 'XData', [.2, .3]); % Changes line two
set(f(6), 'XData', [.2, .3]); % Changes line one
```

But this method doesn't seem to work for the fill. How do I change the size of the fill sample in the legend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fill([0 1 1], [0 1 0], [.9 .9 .9]); hold on
plot(rand(5, 1), 'b');
plot(rand(5, 1), 'r');
plot(rand(5, 1), 'g'); hold off
h = legend('fill', 'line one', 'line two', 'line three');

%# find handles of lines inside legend that have a non-empty tag
hLegendLines = findobj(h, 'type', 'line', '-and', '-regexp','Tag','[^'']');
set(hLegendLines, 'XData', [.2, .3])

%# find handle of patch inside legend
hLegendPatch = findobj(h, 'type', 'patch');
set(hLegendPatch, 'XData', [.2, .2, .3, .3])
```

---

**EDIT**: (response to comments)

You can manipulating the size of the legend by setting the `Position` property. However, it seems that the legend fits its content as tight as possible by default, so you can make it bigger, but not smaller (try resizing it with the mouse):

```
p = get(h,'Position'); p(3)=0.1;
set(h, 'Position',p);
```

[image]

Another way is to reduce the font size used for the labels:

```
h = legend('fill', 'line one', 'line two', 'line three')
set(h, 'FontSize',6);    %# do this before changing the other stuff
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I was hoping this would actually make the legend narrower - is there a way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm generating a ton of plots from a script, so I was trying to avoid having to use the mouse. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: That wasn't the point, using the mouse is the same think as setting the `Position` property from code, yet in both cases you can't shrink the legend beyond what it is..

Answer (score 2):

As of MATLAB R2014b and upwards (the new graphics engine "HG2") legends are implemented differently and the graphics objects found using the original answer no longer exist.

It looks like the "previews" are now `LegendIcon` objects that are accessible as the `Icon` property of the `LegendEntry` object for each entry in the legend. The `LegendEntry` objects are stashed away as children of a hidden property of the `Legend` object called `EntryContainer`.

The `LegendIcon` objects have a `Transform` property which appears to have control of the size of the item in them. To reduce the width, change the first element of the `Matrix` property, which defines the x-axis scaling of the transformation.

To make all entries half as wide, for example, this looks something like the following:

```
hLegend = findobj('Type','legend');
entries = hLegend.EntryContainer.Children;
for entry = entries(:)'
    T = entry.Icon.Transform;
    T.Matrix(1) = T.Matrix(1) / 2;
end
```

Note that as previously, this doesn't make the legend itself narrower. If you try to resize the legend after changing the icon transformations, even to make the legend bigger, the transform seems to reset.