# Reduce the size of the sample patches in the legend of a bar graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to reduce the size of the sample patches in the legend of a bar graph so that they are small squares.

```
x = rand(6,4);
B = bar(x);
BL = legend ((B([1 2 3 4])),{'one','two','three','four'},'fontsize',9);
newPosition = [0.15 0.75 0.15 0.15];
newUnits = 'normalized';
set(BL,'Position', newPosition,'Units', newUnits);
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
hLegendPatch = findobj(BL, 'type', 'patch');
set(hLegendPatch, 'XData', [.2, .2, .3, .3])
```

[image]

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151221/change-the-size-of-a-fill-sample-in-matlab-legend?rq=1

Comment: @natan Thanks so much! Any idea how to reduce the space between the sample patch and the legend text?? :)

Comment: You may want to try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39952475/2627163