# Make squared in legend instead of lines Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, legend

[image: Ditribution of Land use Types]

I have the following code, which plots a 'map' using imagesc, and provides a legend, see output attached.

I am trying to replace the lines in the legend with solid squares. My attamps to far leave the lines and ad hollow squares (including a random square in the top left corner of the figure)

```
figure(6)
imagesc(lut)
title('Ditribution of Land use Types')
ylabel('Longitude')
xlabel('Latitude')
caxis([0, 7])
myColorMap = jet(6);

imagesc(lut, 'AlphaData', ~isnan(lut))
colormap(myColorMap);

L = line(ones(6), ones(6));
set(L, {'Color'}, num2cell(myColorMap, 2))

legend(L, {'Forest','Shrubland','Savanna','Grassland','Agricultural','Barron'})
set(L(:),'Marker','s')
grid on
ax = gca
ax.GridAlpha = .2
ax.XTick = [5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40];
ax.YTick = [5 10 15 20 25 30];
ax.XTickLabel = {'118^{o}E','123^{o}E','128^{o}E', '133^{o}E', '138^{o}E', '143^{o}E','148^{o}E', '153^{o}E'};
ax.YTickLabel = {'13^{o}S','18^{o}S','23^{o}S','28^{o}S','33^{o}S','38^{o}S'};
ax.TickLength =[0.0 0.0]
```

Comment: Not a full answer, but for improvement, you can also set the `'MarkerFaceColor'` of your lines, that will fill the square marker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `nan` to create invisible data (thanks @matlatbgui), and set `L` with all needed properties for no line and filled square markers:

```
% some arbitrary data:
N = 30;
lut = diag(1:N)*ones(N)+(diag(1:N)*ones(N)).';

% coloring settings:
caxis([0, 7])
myColorMap = jet(6);

% plotting:
imagesc(lut, 'AlphaData', ~isnan(lut))
colormap(myColorMap);

% Setting the legend:
L = line(nan(6), nan(6),'LineStyle','none'); % 'nan' creates 'invisible' data
set(L, {'MarkerEdgeColor'}, num2cell(myColorMap, 2),...
    {'MarkerFaceColor'},num2cell(myColorMap, 2),... % setting the markers to filled squares
    'Marker','s'); 
legend(L, {'Forest','Shrubland','Savanna','Grassland','Agricultural','Barron'})
```

and you don't need your line:

```
set(L(:),'Marker','s')
```

[image: legend]

Comment: Indeed! But why `-2` for coordinates? I think you forgot to remove it?

Comment: It's to get rid of the _"random square in the top left corner"_ :)

Comment: Yes, but doesn't that point anyway change the axis limits and appear again? I think you should get the limits and set them after `line` again

Comment: @erfan I have checked that, and it doesn't change the limits.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I did not expect so.

Comment: @EBH great answer! Add a bit of information in the body, to explain what you are doing!

Comment: @AnderBiguri done. Also changed to a nicer picture ;)

Comment: Create your line with `nan` instead of `zeros` and you dont need to worry about them being displayed on your axes.  As `nan` is truly invisible!

Answer (score 1):

The square on the upper-left corner is obviously due to `set(L(:),'Marker','s')` which draws a square at the start and end points of the lines, at `[1, 1]`. Instead of changing the `'Marker'`, if you increase the `'LineWidth'`, you get much better results with:

```
L = line(ones(6), ones(6));
legend(L, {'Forest','Shrubland','Savanna','Grassland','Agricultural','Barron'})
set(L(:), 'LineWidth', 10)
```

With this output:

[image]

So if you are not restricted to make squares, I believe wide rectangles are better flags for color.